# Change $item = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt) to prepared statement style

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

This code works but I am trying to work out how to change the $rose = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt); section to 'prepared statement style'. Anyone know?

```
$rose_id = $_GET['rose_id'];
  //prepare the statement
  $stmt = $conn2->prepare("SELECT * FROM rosename 
            LEFT JOIN rosevariety ON (rosename.variety_name = rosevariety.variety_name) 
            WHERE rose_id = ?");

            //bind the parameters
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $rose_id);

  //$sql = mysql_query($query, $conn);
  $stmt->execute();

  //was there a good response?
  if ($stmt) {

    $rose = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt);

    //echo out rose information
    echo "<h1>".$rose['latin_name']."</h1>";
    echo "<h2>".$rose['common_name']."</h2>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using PDO:

```
$rose = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

If using mysqli:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rose = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: This looks like `mysqli` and **not** `PDO`

Comment: Yes its mysqli. How do i do it for mysqli?

Answer (score 1):

If PDO is used, [$stmt->fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) would be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

```
while ($rose = $stmt->fetch()) {
   //$rose = current row;
}
```

Actually I think to use it correctly you need to do

```
while(($rose = $stmt->fetch()) !== false){
  //$rose = current row;
}
```